# How to multiply this matrix?

Tags: python, matrix

How can I multiply such matrix as below?

I want to multiply A^2 * B , I have a code but it doesn't work.

```py
    import numpy as np
    A = np.array([[0,-1,1], [3,2,2], [1,0,-2]])
    B = np.array([[1,0], [2,1], [-2,7]])
    print (A)
    print(B)

    C=A*A
    print(C)

    C*B
```

+I try to multiply A*B^2 so I write:

```py
D=A@B@B
print(D)
```

but this doesn't work like the previous one..

Comment: Use [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html), or, if you are using a recent Python version (>= 3.5), simply use the `@` operator (`C = A @ A @ B`). The `*` operator performs element-wise multiplication ([Hadamard product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,-1,1], [3,2,2], [1,0,-2]])
B = np.array([[1,0], [2,1], [-2,7]])
print (A)
print(B)

C= A @ A @ B
print(C)


[[ 0 -1  1]
 [ 3  2  2]
 [ 1  0 -2]]
[[ 1  0]
 [ 2  1]
 [-2  7]]
[[  2 -30]
 [  4  22]
 [-14  34]]
```

Comment: Yes,thank you! :) You know why when I want to multiply A@B@B it don't works?

Comment: if you just want to calculate A@B@B, it wont work since the dimensions don't match. (just look at B@B - those dimensions already dont fit). What you want is probably A@B@B.T

Answer (score 0):

how i multiply this type of matrix

```
#2x3
A = [[6],[5],[4],
    [3],[2],[1]]

#3x2
B = [[1],[2],
   [3],[4],
   [5],[6]]

#resultant matrix will be 2x2
result=[[0],[0],[0],
        [0],[0],[0]]

for i in range(len(A)):  
     for j in range(len(B[0])):
          for k in range(len(B)):
               result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]

print("New Matrix Is:",result)
```